# How to find a mirror map with respect to some norm?

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization

I know that a mirror map $\Phi$ with respect to a norm $\|\cdot\|$ need to be strictly convex and differentiable.

For example, $$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2_2$$ is 1-strongly convex w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_2$. And $$\Phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\log x_i$$ is 1-strongly convex w.r.t $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $\Delta_n$.

But how do we find a mirror map in general with respect to some norm?

Comment: What is a "mirror map"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In optmization, a mirror map is a bridge between a primal space and dual space. The gradient of a mirror map sends a point $x \in \mathbf{B}$ to its dual space $\mathbf{B}^*$ so that one can perform descent algorithms.